# read the values of a cell separated by a vertical bar

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains data separated by a vertical bar like this `(A|B|C)`, and I want to read them and assign to a variables such that the:

- first variable refer to `A`,
- the second refer to `B` and so on.

I also want to count the number of these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split`

If your value was in `A1` then the following code automatically puts the first variable in `vArr(0)`, the second in `vArr(1)`. You can loop through the variant array vArr to access the individual values

```
vArr = Split(Range("A1"), "|")
MsgBox "Number of items = " & UBound(vArr) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the fast response ,i am just a beginner and i hope you can help me.thanks again

Comment: Hi - is there any further guidance you need as to how to use or apply this?